# How do I run correlations for each row subsets in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a fictional pandas dataframe `df`.

Suppose that it has three columns: `gender`, `height`, and `weight`

Is there a built in or efficient method to get the correlation of `height` and `weight` for each `gender`?

What I've done so far:

1. Manually filtered the data frames for each gender, and then run
   correlations on each.
2. This has worked on my sample set, but will fall apart in the production set because I have more categories than just `gender`. I have hundreds.

An example of my sub-optimal code:

```
df_m=df[(df['gender']=='male')]
df_m['height'].corr(df_m['weight'])
df_f=df[(df['gender']=='female')]
df_f['height'].corr(df_f['weight'])
```

Ideal Output:

```
'gender' 'correlation'
'male' .9007876876 
'female' .8777687666
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby('gender').apply(lambda x: x.height.corr(x.weight)).rename('correlation').to_frame()
```

The last part (`rename` and `to_frame`) are just to get it to your desired output.

**Example**:

```
>>> df
   gender  height  weight
0    male       1       4
1    male       2       4
2    male       3       5
3  female       1       4
4  female       2       3
5  female       3       5

>>> df.groupby('gender').apply(lambda x: x.height.corr(x.weight)).rename('correlation').to_frame()
        correlation
gender             
female     0.500000
male       0.866025
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! For future readers, if you want to put these values into a new dataframe, just add `df_yourname=` before the code